# DELL VRTX - M620 Blade - Both NICs "Unidentified Network"

Tags: hyper-v, dell-poweredge, dell, windows-server-2019, nic

I have a DELL VRTX with two M620 Blades. I have an issue with one of the Blades. Both NICs come up with "Unidentified network". I got the server 2.5 years ago and run Hyper-V on the Blades. It works without an issue but about 3 weeks ago I started having issues with this.

I've updated all the firmware and all the hardware I was able to find on the DELL website. I am running Server 2019 Standard on both blades. I've formatted the blade in question as a last resort to try to wipe anything that might have been software related with no luck.

BIOS version is 2.9.0

Firmware version is 2.63.60.32

ISDSM Firmware version is 1.10

I've installed the latest drivers from DELL (and intel) for the NICs.

I've checked the VRTX onboard switch to make sure that there are no changes on that side.

Comment: Does networking actually *work* on those servers? Are they able to ping their default gateway?

Comment: Good morning. So one of the has no issues and can ping and access everything. The other one, the one I posted about stop doing that. I used them as noded for Failover cluster, for Hyper-V and I am running on only one of them at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your network looks like, is this machine part of a larger domain of is it an SME single server?

I have had this on Domain Controllers which run DHCP if they are the first to boot after an outage, in which case a disable/enable fixes it (it only affects firewall zone and aesthetics in this case!).

Do you get an IP? If not, is the server on the correct VLAN on your switch and on the chassis switch? Are your vlans trunked correctly all the way through the stack? Is it every blade in the chassis, in which case is the cabling ok?

Comment: Hi there, flat network, only one VLAN. There is a second blade on the VRTX chassis which works fine. I've checked the settings on the onboard VRTX switch to compare between them to see if there was something different for the problematic one, but no. When I disable the ports from the swiss, they come up as "cable disconnected" on the blade, so that match works...